# displaying images in django wrong url

Tags: python, django, image, url

I am using django 1.7. I am facing difficulty in displaying uploaded images. The souce code of page is showing the url

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/user/<user.slug>/images/user/main/IMG_3826.JPG
```

but that folder does not exists. what should i change in my code to remove that `/user/<user.slug>` from it.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
                        (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
                         'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}))
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = (os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'images'))
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'
```

Comment: From where you call this url? means in href="...."????

Comment: its  <img src="{{ page_user.myuserprofile.image }}" class="picture">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I am assuming you have knowledge of custom filter)
The one solution is to make custom template filter to remove "/user/" string from http://127.0.0.1:8888/user//images/user/main/IMG_3826.JPG
 like this. You can find reference in django website to make custom filter.

{{ page_user.myuserprofile.image|remove_url }}

in tempplatetag write this like code:

```
def remove_url(url):
    u = url.split('/')
    u1 = u[0]+"/"+u[3]+"/"+u[4]+"/"+u[5]+"/"+u[6]
    return u1
```

this will return you 
http://127.0.0.1:8888/images/user/main/IMG_3826.JPG

Comment: but that is just a hack. My confusion is regarding why it is directing me to that url. And not only on this page, on other pages also I am facing the same problem

Comment: PLease put forward slash at src and then see:  <img src="/{{ page_user.myuserprofile.image }}